# WCF Serialization and NHibernate Proxy for a Single Entity Reference

Tags: wcf, nhibernate

Suppose there is NHibernate entity "School" with a "Manager" property which references a single entity of type "Person".

To be "WCF ready", Person is decorated with `DataContractAtrribute`. The Fluent NH mapping for School.Manager is `References(s => s.Manager)`.
When an entity of type "School" is sent to the client by WCF I get an exception with the following message:

> "Type 'Castle.Proxies.PersonProxy' cannot be ISerializable and have DataContractAttribute attribute"

Now, this only happens when referencing a single entity (and not through a collection).
My workaround is to disable the proxy by adding `.Not.LazyLoad()` to the `References` clause.

Did anyone encounter this problem or have any idea how to resolve it?

Thanks,
Elad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you chose not to load referenced entities **eagerly**, NHibernate will create dynamic proxies (so that object can be initialized at some point in future). That's standard behavior.

Now, for list of objects, NHibernate will use one of its proxy collections (for example, `PersistentGenericBag`). Since the collection type is known, it can be serialized. What happens when it approaches your entity class instead? It will generate **dynamic proxy** basing on your type, which won't be serializable (thanks to it runtime-oriented/dynamic nature).

This is built in mechanism and I don't think you can do much about it. Yet, you have two solutions to this problem:

- using `Not.LazyLoad()` like you're doing now, to force instance creation
- alternatively, you can set `Manager` to `null` before sending through web service. You won't have any use of proxy on client side (since session will be long gone) anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Extending jimmy_keen's answer, there are some other options

- Set fetchmode to eager for the Reference when loaded before serialization
- Copy the domainobject to a DTO-/message objects to send over the wire (good practice to have more control, what goes over the wire)
- implementing `IDataContractSurrogate` see [here](http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/nhusers@googlegroups.com/2010-02/msg00042.html)