# WCF parameter serializing Error

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I´m getting an WCF Error on Serverside:

There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:GetUserResult. The InnerException message was 'Type 'RoleProxy' with data contract name RoleProxy:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/' is not expected. ...

My Problem is, that I dont have any RoleProxy Type, that could be serialized.

I have the following Class:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Permission))]
public class Role
{
    protected virtual long _ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual long ID
    {
        get { return _ID; }
        // zum Test
        set { _ID = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual bool IsDefault { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }

    public Role()
    {

    }

    public Role(string name, ICollection<Permission> permissions, bool isDefault = false)
    {
        Name = name;
        Permissions = permissions;
        IsDefault = isDefault;
    }

    public virtual bool HasPermission(Permission perm)
    {
        foreach(Permission permission in this.Permissions)
            if (permission.Equals(perm))
                return true;

        return false;
    }

    public virtual bool Equals(Role other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return Equals(other.Name, Name);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != typeof(Role)) return false;
        return Equals((Role)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

and here is the function i am calling:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Role))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(User))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Permission))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(IList<Role>))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(IList<User>))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(IList<Permission>))]
public interface ISecurityManager
{
    ...

    [OperationContract]
    User GetUser(string userDomain, string userName);

    ...

}
```

The Result is received correctly by the server, but there is some serialitation problem which I coulndt find. Any solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: What ORM you use to create Role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ORMs such as EF and NHibernate like to create proxy types at runtime that extend the default behaviour. Most regular code won't care that it has a sub-type (Liskov substitution principle, etc) - but: inheritance aware serializers need to check what object they are actually working with.

Dealing with dynamic proxy types is a pain; some serializers can handle some proxies (i.e. by not treating the proxy as an unexpected sub-type, but instead serializing it *as if* it was the base type), but it is by no means universal. The most practical thing to do is to map your data back into a `Role` instance, to **make sure** that what you give WCF is the object you told it about. AutoMapper might make a convenient implementation for such.

As an additional observation, this also means that you `Equals` code is wrong:

```
    if (obj.GetType() != typeof(Role)) return false;
    return Equals((Role)obj);
```

should be:

```
    return Equals(obj as Role);
```

(noting that `Equals(Role)` already handles the `null` case correctly for us)

Comment: Do you have an example of using automapper?

Comment: @user1663907 for that scenerio? just `var fixed = Mapper.Map<Role>(role);`, and give `fixed` to WCF

Comment: But I want to return a User not a Role. The Role is just a property of User... I dont get the point. Additionally your code wont work, cause you need to provide a destination mapping class like `var mapping = Mapper.Map<Role,destination>(role)`;

Comment: @user1663907 the code you showed related to `Role`. Feel free to change the mapping, but: for mapping a `Role`, the code I posted works just fine (I did verify it locally, etc). However, as long as you are returning NHibernate proxies, WCF is not going to be your friend.

Comment: After some more research, I found this topic ... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165466/wcf-serialization-and-nhibernate-proxy-for-a-single-entity-reference). Some people recomended also to set lazy=false ... i did so and it worked. It also saves trafic over the wire :)